# How to add + in front of positive integers before string concatenation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd

zed = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': [3, -5], 'b': [-4, 7]})
zed['c'] = zed['a'].astype(str) + ' ' + zed['b'].astype(str)
```

Which gives:

```
    a   b   c
0   3   -4  3 -4
1   -5  7   -5 7
```

But I am looking for column `c` to be:

```
    a   b   c
0   3   -4  +3 -4
1   -5  7   -5 +7
```

i.e. the positive numbers should have a `+` prefix.

my code gets messy very quickly when I add `if/else` conditionals everywhere. I have created the following function:

```
def plus_prefix(a):
    if a > 0:
        b = '+' + a.astype(str)
    else:
        b = a.astype(str)
    return b
```

but `zed['c'] = plus_prefix(zed['a']) + ' ' + plus_prefix(zed['b'])` throws an error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. How can this be improved? Would be great if I could create `plus_prefix` so that it can be chained at the end, `zed['a'].plus_prefix()`.

Comment: Would be helpful if you showed the **desired** output next to the actual output.

Comment: **we are looking for column c to be** is right there in the question

Comment: "we are looking for column c to be"? What kind of output is that???

Comment: Right below that sentence is a display of what column c should look like. Not quite sure how this could be made more clear.

Comment: You want all the positive numbers in column C (and in column C only) to be printed with a `+` next to them?

Comment: The [`+` format modifier](https://pyformat.info/#number_sign) does that. i.e. `'{:+d}'.format(42)` gives `"+42"`. Not sure how to incorporate this into pandas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `apply()` method to apply a function onto a DataFrame ([see documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)):

```
zed['c'] = zed['a'].apply(plus_prefix) + ' ' + zed['b'].apply(plus_prefix)
```

However, since your values are integers, I got a new error since it doesn't know `astype()`. After modifying your function, I was able to get it to work:

```
import pandas as pd

def plus_prefix(a):
    if a > 0:
        b = '+' + str(a)
    else:
        b = str(a)
    return b

zed = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': [3, -5], 'b': [-4, 7]})
zed['c'] = zed['a'].apply(plus_prefix) + ' ' + zed['b'].apply(plus_prefix)
```

Comment: @Canovice `plus_prefix` can simply be `return f"{a:+}"`

Answer (score 2):

That should do the trick:

```
zed['c'] = zed['a'].apply(lambda x: '{:+}'.format(x)) + ' ' + zed['b'].apply(lambda x: '{:+}'.format(x))
```

### Python >= 3.6

As [@Tomerikoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6045800/tomerikoo) suggested the code can be simplified using f-String:

```
zed['c'] = zed['a'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:+}') + ' ' + zed['b'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:+}')
```

Comment: Yeah you are right thanks, I edited the answer

Comment: By the way, as I suggested in the other answer, using Python >= 3.6 f-strings make this even simpler: `lambda x: f"{x:+}"`